# Working with searches and query API. Executing a SOQL query using "IN" clause

Tags: soql, community, rest-api, query, soap-api

> select Id, Name from Contact where Email in
>   ('apple+super@gmail.com','apple+100@gmail.com')

Can anyone help me to query this using the salesforce query api endpoint.

The endpoint that I have tried

> https://{myWorkplaceDomainUsed}--sandbox.cs67.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+Id+from+Contact+where+Email=%27apple+super@gmail.com%27

and the response that I get is:

```
{
    "totalSize": 0,
    "done": true,
    "records": []
}
```

Records are present in salesforce but the result is not displayed.

I even tried escaping query string with "\". The URL that I used is:

> https://{myWorkplaceDomainUsed}--sandbox.cs67.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+Id+from+Contact+where+Email=\'apple+super@gmail.com\'

and the malformed query is the resulting respone.

**What will be the correct way to query my SOQL using "IN" clause?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: ytiq has provided the answer, but workbench is always available for you to try to figure out the right format as well and quickly test. Utilities --> REST Explorer

Comment: update response with code for 'IN' and also added escaping for '+'

Answer (score 1):

You should put ' ', but you don't need to escape them try that one `https://{myWorkplaceDomainUsed}--sandbox.cs67.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+Id+from+Contact+where+Email='apple+super@gmail.com'`.

If you want `IN` you can use it like this `https://{myWorkplaceDomainUsed}--sandbox.cs67.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+Id+from+Contact+where+Email+IN+('apple+super@gmail.com', 'email@test.com')`

**UPDATE:**
Code for IN close with escaping for '+' emails

```
List<String> emails = new List<String>();
// init emails;

String emailString = '(\'' + String.join(emails, '\', \'') + '\''.replaceAll('\\+', '\\\\+');

String query = '... Email IN ' + emailString;
```

Comment: Ytiq, The IN clause query works fine when I don't have any email with the "+" character sign on it. When there is the "+" character it simply returns no record at all. Looks like this thinks "+" as space. As I think the single quote ( ' ' ) should avoid the inside quote character as string right? Could you please help me on querying an email with "+" sign in it. Thank you!

Comment: Also My Email address will be a dynamic variable.

Comment: Then uriEncode +, thought maybe it's a space. Didn't know that email can have +

Comment: Just add your variable as a string `'Select... Email=\''+variable+'\'...'